# Read REG_Binary

Tags: vb.net

I have this code to read registry value, replace some pieces of it and then store it into a text file:

```
Dim key As Object = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\\APP", "KEY", Nothing
Dim Number1 As String
Dim output As String
Output = key
Number1 = "12345"
output = Replace(output, "1", Number1)
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:/value.txt", output, True)
```

Now it works perfectly for all kinds of registry keys except the `REG_BINARY` keys … When I try to read a REG_BINARY key I get this error:

> Conversion from type `Byte()` to type `String` is not valid.

In another words, can I read `REG_BINARY` registry keys – for example `C5 A2 A3 C1` – into string (text) and then replace number 1 from the text?

Comment: Binary data is not text.  What do you want to do with binary values?

Comment: I want to grab REG value ,replace piece of it and then store it into txt file .

Comment: Then replace a byte, not a character.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Binary data is not text.

Comment: This is good. There are number of ways to deal with strings being binary, but binary not being a string. However you have given us no clue as to which one to suggest.  Why are you putting them in a file for instance?

Comment: Ok , even If i try to show the value on message box for example i get no result .

Comment: In another words , can I convert the bytes into txt and then replace the text ?

Comment: @user1970090: **No.  Bytes are not text**.  Your question doesn't actually make sense.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You want to replace a piece of binary data? That would almost certainly just break it.

Comment: LOL you misunderstood me hardly . This REG value for example "C5 A2 A3 C3" , how can I read it in VB.NET in this form ?

Comment: Now that you've specified what kind of strings you want, this question is answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `BitConverter.ToString()`, which will convert a byte array into a string of hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: Yea i think , but how can i use it in the above mentioned code ?
EDIT : nvm got it working . thanks

Comment: Check `If TypeOf key Is Byte()`